# What is the easiest way to run a VM that executes a simple C program

Tags: virtual-machine, fork

I'm trying to run a simple one file C program in a Virtual Machine. In fact it is the fork bomb c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
 
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        fork();   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to do this in order to check how much of an effect this VM would have on another VMs running on the system.

I was wondering what is the easiest way to execute this in a VM, and if possible to avoid downloading, compiling and building a whole Ubuntu/other Linux VM. I often use Unikernels for such things, however most of the ones I know do not have a support for the fork() system call.

Comment: Asking for the *easiest* way to do, without even mentioning alternatives, it is as close as you can get to requesting an opinion based answer (reason to close the question). Look for tutorials on how to run different VMs on your system (whatever it might be, you don't say) and by skimming them you might be able to exclude some of the more difficult approaches. Then, if a particular on-topic issue arises, you could ask about it here.

Comment: Thanks @EduardoTrápani, I wasn't aware that opinion-based questions are not allowed. I will close the question and try to work as suggested.

Comment: If you wan't a payload which act as an OS with a fork syscall, the best think to do is to get one such OS. There are some light OS like Alpine Linux, Damn Small Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With qemu kvm, booting the host kernel in a headless VM with console I/O on serial (redirected to the terminal you run it from):

- Compile that `fork-bomb.c` into a static `init` executable:

  ```
  gcc -static -o init fork-bomb.c
  ```
- Make an initramfs with just that `init` at the root:

  ```
  bsdtar --format newc -cf initrd init
  ```
- Boot the VM on it:

  ```
  kvm -nographic \
      -kernel "/boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)" \
      -initrd initrd \
      -append 'console=ttyS0 debug=9'
  ```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>x</kbd> to terminate the VM.

You can add a `-m 4G` to get 4GiB of RAM instead of the default of 128MiB, `-smp 4` to get 4 CPUs instead of just 1. See `man qemu-system-x86_64` for other ways to customize the virtual hardware. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> to get the qemu monitor console where you can hotplug more components or inspect the state / config of the VM, suspend, save state, etc.

Here we enable the maximum Linux kernel debug level with `debug=9`; you can change it at run time by sending sysrq followed by a digit. With console on serial, sysrq is by sending a "break", which here you'd do with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this in a lot of detail. I managed to run as recommended. I found the last part about interacting with QEMU most helpful. I've been using QEMU for almost a year now, but didn't know these shortcuts.